# Is it possible to customize Dconf's file storing path?

Tags: configuration, synchronization, dconf

Is it possible to customize `Dconf`'s file storing path?

I'd like to store `Dconf` configuration file in one of my synced directory, like `Google-Drive`/`Dropbox` or any other for constant syncing.

Let's say I have Dropbox auto synced directory at `~/Dropbox`

I'd like to store `Dconf` config file at:
`~/Dropbox/dconf`
so that it's is autamatically synchronised (by Dropbox client) and I have settings backuped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man 7 dconf` explains that the user configuration is saved by default in file `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf/user`. Depending on your system, this often means file `~/.config/dconf/user` when `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not defined.

You should be able to move this directory to the wanted place, and replace  it with a symbolic link. Eg

```
mv ~/.config/dconf ~/Dropbox/
ln -s ~/Dropbox/dconf ~/.config/dconf
```

---

Alternatively, you can make a *bind mount* which makes the same directory appear in 2 different places:

```
mkdir ~/Dropbox/dconf
sudo mount -o bind ~/.config/dconf ~/Dropbox/dconf
```

To undo the binding use `sudo umount ~/Dropbox/dconf`.

Comment: I'd would be also awesome if this works with `git` repository (instead of `Google Drive`) but according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791647/740067 it doesn't. :(

Comment: I added an alternative answer using `mount` that should work.